# Faraday's law in free space explaining away the constant vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

Let's say that I have a plane electromagnetic wave travailing in free space, and I know the electric field part to be $\vec E$. If I am using Faraday's law to get the magnetic field part I will get the following:
$$\vec B =\vec B_0+\vec f$$
Where $\vec B_0=\int(-\nabla \times \vec E)dt$ but without the constant of integration and $\vec f$ is that constant of integration. When ever I see this stated the vector $\vec f$ is always set to the zero vector. Why is this? I.e. why can we say that there is no constant 'background' magnetic field and therefore conclude that $\vec f=0$?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you have seen this? A link or description to establish some context will he helpful. @Joseph